# How to reference an area in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a region of cells/columns selected in a sheet, say this region is called "Mo" and the sheen is named "Counter" I would reference this region Counter.Mo in a Find.Vert function but calling it is not working and gives me an error.

How can I correctly reference the area from another sheet?

Comment: Just use "Mo" as reference; drop the sheet name. Range names are unique over the complete file.

Comment: @tohuwawohu this was the case in earlier versions... my LO accepts (same) names defined on sheet level.

Comment: Then you should add the version and OS you're using. I've tested with LO 5.1.4.2 on Linux Mint, working perfectly fine.

Comment: @tohuwawohu working for me both ways (adding the sheet name before a dot, if the range is referenced on another sheet, only range name on same sheet; but not tested with this special formula).
LO 5.2.3.3 openSuse

Answer (score 0):

The feature that you are looking for has been added in [LibreOffice 5.2](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.2#Using_named_expressions_and_ranges_with_sheet-local_scope_on_other_sheets). In older versions the scope of the range name could either be global which meant that it was available everywhere or sheet local which meant that it could only be used in that sheet. The improvement from 5.2 allows to reference the name now also from other sheets by adding the sheet name as scope prefix in the formula.